# AngularJS navigation and URI params oddity

Tags: angularjs

I'm still getting my head around the way Angular works and I've found something odd.

I'm working on an app that's using a master page and templates and the page that I'm creating accepts several URI params and has a page JS that sets the content of a `div` when the page is loaded. When the page is first navigated to or refreshed then the `div` is populated with the expected content, however if the URI params are changed (which typically happens when the user selects links on the page itself) then the `div`'s content isn't set (so it stays at it's original value hardcoded in the html) even though in debug I can see the JS setting its content correctly.

I don't understand how the `div`'s content can be set in the JS but that value doesn't end up in the final html. The same thing happens on at least one other page in the app and on multiple browsers. I'm clearly missing some Angular knowledge!!

Comment: can you http://plnkr.co your code so that we can debug it??

Comment: Attach fiddle please/

Comment: are you sure, you are not using jQuery inside angular controller?